# Make element inside Div Vertically center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[My code here](http://www.bootply.com/Hf1BaEIOP6#)

```
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                Apple
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                Banana
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                Abc
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                xyz
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file" style="float: left;">
                            Browse… <input type="file" id="uploadBtn" name="upload">
                        </span>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!--<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                            Favourite food
                        </label>-->

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>

                                <input type="checkbox">
                                Apple

                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>

                                <input type="checkbox">
                                Banana

                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file" style="float: left;">
                            Browse… <input type="file" id="uploadBtn" name="upload">
                        </span>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

Here The Browse button resides at the top of the div, I want to bring it to vertically center with checkbox div.

Want something like [image]

I tried:

```
 .form-group {
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is useful to solve this. Add a new class to the **parent** of the two blocks you wish to align center - with your code as-is that is the `.row` like so:

```
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here's a working example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgZLyO)